# jQuery Toggle DIV when clicked at index value and change image at index of clicked DIV

Tags: jquery, html

I have a project where I am displaying an array of divs. When I click a div, be it index value of 0,1,2,...n a drop down menu will display from the clicked div. I have it currently set up to where when the div is clicked the drop down displays and the image contained in the div will change(like a (+) to a (-) image for example), thus indicating that the div is opened. I have coded a response so I know the index value of the clicked div and I display this in a `<span>`, (this is just to help me see the index value while I debug.) When I click the div the image will change in the appropriate div, but The problem is no matter what div I click, the div at index value(0) is the only one that drop downs to display my menu. I want the div that is clicked to change the image(working) and also display the menu(broken, except on index(0).

CSS

```
   .hidden { display: none; }
```

HTML

```
   <div class="geolink-bar">
       <div id="arrow">
           <img src="https://geoto.s3.amazonaws.com/images/arrow_down.png">
       </div>
   </div>
   <div id="dropdown-mobile-account" class="hidden">
       <div>Display after geolink-bar is clicked</div>
   </div>
   <span></span>
```

SCRIPT

```
   $(document).ready( function() {
       $('.geolink-bar').click(function(){
           var index = $('.geolink-bar').index(this);
           $("span").text("That was div index #" + index);//DISPLAYS INDEX NUMBER F DIV CLICKED     
           $('#dropdown-mobile-account').slideToggle("slow");
           $(this).html(function(i,html) {
              if (html.indexOf('Show') != -1 ){
                  html = html.replace('Show','Hide');
              } else {
              html = html.replace('Hide','Show');
              }
              return html;
           }).find('img').attr('src',function(i,src){
           return (src.indexOf('arrow_down.png') != -1)? 'https://geoto.s3.amazonaws.com/images/arrow_open.png' :'https://geoto.s3.amazonaws.com/images/arrow_down.png';
           });
       }); 
   });
```

Comment: Is `#dropdown-mobile-account` the menu? If you've given the same id attribute to multiple elements you've created invalid html and that selector will only find the first one. If you want to drop down the div that immediately follows the clicked one use `$(this).next().slideToggle("slow");`. If that's not the problem please show more of your markup so we can see several menu items - perhaps make a demo at http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: Thank you. This is the fix I was looking for. I replaced my        **$('#dropdown-mobile-account').slideToggle("slow");**
with **$(this).next().slideToggle("slow");**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to "nnnnnn's" comment, I replaced my

```
    $('#dropdown-mobile-account').slideToggle("slow");
```

with

```
    $(this).next().slideToggle("slow");
```

"RoXon's" example is a very good demo to take a look @ as well. :-)

Answer (score 1):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/agosat/3/edit)*

CSS:

```
.dropdown-mobile-account{
    display:none;
}
```

HTML:

```
   <div class="geolink-bar">
     <span class="tog-txt">Show</span>
       <div class="arrow">
           <img src="https://geoto.s3.amazonaws.com/images/arrow_down.png">
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="dropdown-mobile-account">
       <div>Display after geolink-bar is clicked</div>
   </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.geolink-bar').click(function() {
    
      var visible = $(this).next('.dropdown-mobile-account').is(':visible'),
         slideTog = visible?'slideUp':'slideDown',
              txt = visible?'Show':'Hide',
           arrUrl = ['https://geoto.s3.amazonaws.com/images/arrow_down.png', 'https://geoto.s3.amazonaws.com/images/arrow_open.png'],
            arrow = visible? arrUrl[0] : arrUrl[1];
       
      $('.dropdown-mobile-account').slideUp();
      $('span.tog-txt').text('Show');
      $('.arrow').find('img').attr('src', arrUrl[0] );
      
      $(this).find('span.tog-txt').text( txt ).end().find('img').attr('src', arrow).end().next('.dropdown-mobile-account')[slideTog]();

});
```

Comment: Although I ended using  'nnnnnn's' simple fix, I still thank you very much for your example code. I would give you a plus one but I am unable to due to my (rating<15).